# Matching documents from different sets with tfidf and cosine distance

Tags: dataset, tfidf, cosine-distance, similar-documents, document-term-matrix

I have two different set of documents `S1`, `S2`, with 30 text documents each.
Using some text representation method, such as tfidf and a distance measure, such as cosine similarity, I want to match similar documents from the two sets `S1, S2`.

For example `D1 from S1` is similar (say 0.36 similar ) to `D28 from S2`.

My problem is that `Tfidf.Vectorizer()` creates an array of `30, 5000` for `S1` and `30, 4500` for `S2`, with 30 *rows for each document* and *words of all the documents as columns*.

If I calculate `cosine_similarity=(S1, S2)` vectorized products, I will simply get the similarity between sets as a whole, which is not what I am trying here. I am not interested in finding similarity between documents inside the same set.

Question is:

Is there a way to vectorize each document, for each set, on its own and then calculate pairs distance?

Or is there a way to implement the above method, and then find which documents are similar, based on the *tfidf matrix* of the set, as described above?

Comment: I believe you can try document level embedding. Then, once you have an embedding for two documents say A and B, use cosine similarity to check how similar they are.